# QML - How to drag a ToolButton?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

The QT documentation has this [tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-tutorials-dynamicview-dynamicview3-example.html).

I initially followed it exactly, and it works.  I then made two modifications:

1. I replaced the ListView with a GridView (that works without #2).
2. I attempted to add a ToolButton to my delegate inside the Rectangle "content" like so:

---

```
Rectangle {
    id: content

    ToolButton {
        id: toolButton
        icon.color = "transparent"
        icon.source = "image://Loader/iconName"
    }
    Drag.active: dragArea.held
    Drag.source: dragArea
    Drag.hotSpot.x: width / 2
    Drag.hotSpot.y: height / 2
}
```

This does not work, the ToolButton appears to be processing the mouse movements and not propagating the messages (I can click the button, but I can not drag it)?  This is actually somewhat expected to be honest.

So that said, does anyone have a good way of dragging ToolButtons around?  Or is it just accepted that you can't do that? I have tried various combinations of Rectangles and MouseAreas but I can't seem to do one without breaking the other (ie either the drag fails or the button fails).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to drag a ToolButton? What is the use case?

Comment: Where is `dragArea`?

Comment: I want to allow the user to be able to customize the ToolBar (drag buttons left/right/up/down to re-order them).  I can do this via a completely separate Customization window, but it is much simpler to just allow the user to drag the buttons around.

As for the dragArea, I did not copy/paste all the code (the rest of the code can be found in the link at the top).

Comment: Maybe if you set [`MouseArea.propagateComposedEvents`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#propagateComposedEvents-prop) to `true` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `MouseArea` as a child of the `ToolButton` to manage the drag with `pressAndHold`, and propagate the click to keep the button behavior:

```
Rectangle {
    id: content

    ToolButton {
        id: toolButton

        // bind the visual state of the button to the MouseArea
        background: Rectangle {
            color: marea.pressed
                   ? Qt.darker("blue")
                   : marea.containsMouse
                     ? Qt.lighter("blue")
                     : "blue" // use your desired colors
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: marea

            property bool held: false

            drag.target: held ? content : undefined
            drag.axis: Drag.YAxis

            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onPressAndHold: held = true
            onReleased: held = false
            onClicked: toolButton.clicked() // propagate clicked event to the ToolButton
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That is a good idea, I tried something similar but didn't think to propagate the click in that manner.  I will give it a try, thanks!